# resumed batch jobs get stuck

Tags: batch-processing, mulesoft, mule4

I have the problem that I cannot
resume stopped batch jobs with my custom connector.
After executing the resume(),
only the status changes to 'EXECUTING' and I get the console log that my batch job has been resumed
but the batch job is not executed any further.

In this case, a batch job increments up to 9. Each increment is stored in the ObjectStore and has a waiting time of 30s.
The batch job has 3 batch steps and each step increases the total value by 3.

Console Logs:

```
INFO  2023-11-08 11:29:58,442 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [test-batch-manager].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$17:435 @2410ae2b] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'PATCH-Stop-BatchJobs' successfully started
INFO  2023-11-08 11:29:58,442 [[MuleRuntime].uber.09: [test-batch-manager].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$17:435 @4cc41a45] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'PATCH-Resume-BatchJobs' successfully started
INFO  2023-11-08 11:29:58,442 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$17:435 @2e321f9f] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'PATCH-Cancel-BatchJobs' successfully started
INFO  2023-11-08 11:29:58,442 [[MuleRuntime].uber.07: [test-batch-manager].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$17:435 @4f1f77e9] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'GET-BatchJobs' successfully started
INFO  2023-11-08 11:29:58,442 [[MuleRuntime].uber.06: [test-batch-manager].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$17:435 @345b9cf0] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'GET-RetrieveBatchJobInfo' successfully started
INFO  2023-11-08 11:29:58,442 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [test-batch-manager].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$17:435 @51cb6c6e] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'POST-Error' successfully started
INFO  2023-11-08 11:29:58,442 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$null$17:435 @64051921] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'POST-addBatchJob' successfully started
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:09,818 [[MuleRuntime].uber.09: [test-batch-manager].POST-addBatchJob.CPU_INTENSIVE @2062fec] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/3; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 32102d80-529f-4d60-a5f4-b317dc87c734
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:09,921 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].POST-addBatchJob.BLOCKING @d789c1e] [processor: ; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Created instance 'caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf' for batch job 'batchjobfe2'
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:09,929 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].POST-addBatchJob.BLOCKING @d789c1e] [processor: ; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Starting loading phase for instance 'caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf' of job 'batchjobfe2'
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:09,964 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].POST-addBatchJob.BLOCKING @d789c1e] [processor: ; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Finished loading phase for instance caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf of job batchjobfe2. 1 records were loaded
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:09,971 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].POST-addBatchJob.BLOCKING @d789c1e] [processor: ; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Started execution of instance 'caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf' of job 'batchjobfe2'
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:10,029 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/0/processors/0; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: start
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:20,119 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/0/processors/2/processors/1; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 1
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:26,827 [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [test-batch-manager].GET-BatchJobs.CPU_LITE @578bbb8c] [processor: GET-BatchJobs/processors/0; event: d5096f91-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: attributes.queryParams.batchjobkey
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:30,137 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/0/processors/2/processors/1; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 2
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:40,154 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/0/processors/2/processors/1; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 3
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:40,165 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/0/processors/3; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 3
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:40,197 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: ; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.DefaultBatchStep: Step Start finished processing all records for instance caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf of job batchjobfe2
INFO  2023-11-08 11:30:50,222 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/1/processors/0/processors/1; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 4
INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:00,244 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/1/processors/0/processors/1; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 5
INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:10,258 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/1/processors/0/processors/1; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 6
INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:10,263 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: POST-addBatchJob/processors/6/route/0/route/1/processors/1; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 6
INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:10,276 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].batch-job-batchjobfe2-work-manager @3816f66f] [processor: ; event: cad74470-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.DefaultBatchStep: Step Middle finished processing all records for instance caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf of job batchjobfe2
INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:10,281 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-management-work-manager @18e9386] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: 

INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:10,282 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12: [test-batch-manager].batch-management-work-manager @18e9386] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: instance caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf of job batchjobfe2 has been stopped. Instance status is STOPPED
INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:38,502 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].PATCH-Resume-BatchJobs.CPU_LITE @2fb6e98] [processor: PATCH-Resume-BatchJobs/processors/0; event: ffc0f3c0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.internal.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: instance 'caf294a0-7e21-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf' of job 'batchjobfe2' has been resumed
INFO  2023-11-08 11:31:55,505 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].GET-BatchJobs.CPU_LITE @578bbb8c] [processor: GET-BatchJobs/processors/0; event: 09e4c700-7e22-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: attributes.queryParams.batchjobkey
INFO  2023-11-08 11:35:03,176 [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [test-batch-manager].GET-RetrieveBatchJobInfo.CPU_LITE @40b7b753] [processor: GET-RetrieveBatchJobInfo/processors/0; event: 79c0cb51-7e22-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 32102d80-529f-4d60-a5f4-b317dc87c734
INFO  2023-11-08 11:35:03,182 [[MuleRuntime].uber.11: [test-batch-manager].GET-RetrieveBatchJobInfo.BLOCKING @3045ae9f] [processor: GET-RetrieveBatchJobInfo/processors/2; event: 79c0cb51-7e22-11ee-91d6-001fb52ce1cf] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 6
```

Resume Method:

```
package org.mule.extension.batchmanager.internal;


import com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.api.BatchJob;
import com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.api.BatchJobInstance;
import com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.api.BatchJobInstanceStatus;
import com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.module.batch.api.BatchManager;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.mule.extension.batchmanager.internal.metadata.BatchJobListStaticTypeResolver;
import org.mule.runtime.api.artifact.Registry;
import org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleException;
import org.mule.runtime.extension.api.annotation.metadata.OutputResolver;
import org.mule.runtime.extension.api.annotation.param.Config;
import org.mule.runtime.extension.api.annotation.param.Connection;
import org.mule.runtime.extension.api.annotation.param.MediaType;
import org.mule.runtime.extension.api.annotation.param.display.DisplayName;

/**
 * This class is a container for operations, every public method in this class
 * will be taken as an extension operation.
 */
// BatchManager - Interface
// DefaultBatchManager - Internal(no access) - Implements BatchManager
// batchManager.getJobInstance(name, id);
public class BatchManagerOperations {

    @Inject
    private Registry muleRegistry;

    public BatchManagerOperations(Registry muleRegistry) {
        this.muleRegistry = muleRegistry;
    }

    public BatchManagerOperations() {
    }
    @MediaType("application/plain")
    @DisplayName(value = "Batch Manager - Resume a Batch Job")
    public String resumeBatchJob(String batchJobName, String batchJobId) throws MuleException {
        String message = "";
        List<BatchJobInstanceStatus> checks = new ArrayList<BatchJobInstanceStatus>(
                Arrays.asList(BatchJobInstanceStatus.STOPPED));
        Optional<BatchManager> reslut = this.muleRegistry.lookupByType(BatchManager.class);

        if (!reslut.isPresent())
            return message;
        BatchManager batchManager = (BatchManager) reslut.get();

        BatchJobInstance batchJobInstance = batchManager.getJobInstance(batchJobName, batchJobId);
        
        if(batchJobInstance == null) {
            message = "Could not find this Batch Job";
        } else if (checks.contains(batchJobInstance.getStatus())) {
            batchManager.resume(batchJobName, batchJobId);
            message = "Batch Job has been resumed";
        } else {
            message = "Batch Job doesn't have the correct status";
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

Message Flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:validation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation" xmlns:os="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os"
    xmlns:batch-manager="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch-manager"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:batchmanager="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batchmanager" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batchmanager http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batchmanager/current/mule-batchmanager.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch-manager http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch-manager/current/mule-batch-manager.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os/current/mule-os.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation/current/mule-validation.xsd">
    <flow name="POST-addBatchJob" doc:id="0e6ee8d0-5476-4c9b-addb-9b461453a12a" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="2f4f7769-aee6-4f26-b9d7-eacb04265967" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" allowedMethods="POST" path="/batchjob"/>
<ee:transform doc:name="prepare list" doc:id="2a1786db-9047-4b5b-9472-796e2ddce886" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
fun prepareList(list: Array, maxSize: Number) = if(sizeOf(list)>=maxSize)
list
else
prepareList(list ++ [(sizeOf(list)+1) as Number], maxSize)
---
{
    list: prepareList([],3)
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <set-variable value="#[payload.list]" doc:name="List" doc:id="9824d1dd-6e6a-400b-8773-452950d79550" variableName="list"/>
        <set-variable value="#[uuid()]" doc:name="ID" doc:id="131abdae-d910-4ab2-a25e-075c96156be4" variableName="id"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="ID" doc:id="dc7ea4ca-4173-4439-95dd-9e8356e8efd8" message="#[vars.id]"/>
        <os:store doc:name="Store" doc:id="0a95468e-9c22-4a9c-8c4b-f0cc3edd490d" key="#[vars.id]">
            <os:value><![CDATA[#[0]]]></os:value>
        </os:store>
        <set-variable value="#[sizeOf(payload)]" doc:name="size" doc:id="014044f5-06eb-4873-87ec-d45edc40605b" variableName="size" />
        <batch:job jobName="batchjobfe2" doc:id="869f48a1-5f7b-4383-a23b-5a9135be0c08" blockSize="1" schedulingStrategy="ROUND_ROBIN">
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Start" doc:id="76e70a4f-7f3d-40ec-8ecd-26ca69c87e31" >
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Start" doc:id="c8f040ce-c39b-4ccc-ab18-9ec432de3ea5" message="start" />
                    <set-variable value="#[0 as Number]" doc:name="Batch Counter" doc:id="4489e7d3-346e-46f6-963e-41b4929b24d1" variableName="batchCounter" />
                    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="d480c442-2bba-4bb7-9673-7c308ce2f3e5" collection="#[vars.list]" >
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="67e041a3-e9e2-485d-8711-b30a713ce581" >
                            <ee:message >
                                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
output application/json
---
{
    counter: vars.batchCounter + 1
} wait 10000
 ]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Counter" doc:id="4bde01bf-a68d-4d76-99b4-7dfec80d9604" message="#[payload.counter]" />
                        <set-variable value="#[payload.counter]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="61772888-2b9a-415c-aa7c-9fb4c0bba00f" variableName="batchCounter" />
                        <os:store doc:name="Store" doc:id="b51d2a0c-ad23-49d3-8257-405dced8164d" key="#[vars.id]" >
                            <os:value ><![CDATA[#[payload.counter]]]></os:value>
                        </os:store>
                    </foreach>
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Batch Counter1" doc:id="01a70d0f-90df-4bc8-8cb8-047c6363512c" message="#[vars.batchCounter]" />
                </batch:step>
                <batch:step name="Middle" doc:id="07417316-cd53-46bc-8da4-070ca16b71f8" >
                    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="f7dccb32-3b55-4f70-bfb6-cd655ee4429b" collection="#[vars.list]" >
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="96a19451-5400-484b-9530-f382f0d66e7b" >
                            <ee:message >
                                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
output application/json
---
{
    counter: vars.batchCounter + 1
} wait 10000
 ]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Counter" doc:id="1b1a7d11-7cd6-4873-805e-5ad4906083cd" message="#[payload.counter]" />
                        <set-variable value="#[payload.counter]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="43161277-5376-490f-8ac2-a038a8e03609" variableName="batchCounter" />
                        <os:store doc:name="Store" doc:id="b6c6922c-58ae-4f3f-b0b4-d70d8dbac9a9" key="#[vars.id]" >
                            <os:value ><![CDATA[#[payload.counter]]]></os:value>
                        </os:store>
                    </foreach>
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Batch Counter" doc:id="46c241ea-8e59-4bdc-9f2f-33f4a7f8c9af" message="#[vars.batchCounter]" />
                </batch:step>
                <batch:step name="End" doc:id="4ed7a248-ecca-447b-9176-b8b12566f9b9" >
                    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="02b74a91-5a7d-4b8c-a78a-8ecfd7d152ea" collection="#[vars.list]" >
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="b6fa4407-f609-44c4-9f24-d910da71baf5" >
                            <ee:message >
                                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
output application/json
---
{
    counter: vars.batchCounter + 1
} wait 10000
 ]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Counter" doc:id="009d7da4-0ed1-432f-953f-ba837379d783" message="#[payload.counter]" />
                        <set-variable value="#[payload.counter]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="3502098a-1093-48f5-a63b-f10a61c456f0" variableName="batchCounter" />
                        <os:store doc:name="Store" doc:id="f97b6481-c589-494a-aeb1-39257a0fa827" key="#[vars.id]" >
                            <os:value ><![CDATA[#[payload.counter]]]></os:value>
                        </os:store>
                    </foreach>
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Batch Counter" doc:id="ff2bbad0-202e-4587-818b-7e1ee6e90f24" message="#[vars.batchCounter]" />
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="End" doc:id="9599b098-9180-431a-9123-2b498288922d" message="end" />
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
        </batch:job>
        <set-payload value="#[vars.id]" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="d3b0ea4e-f0cb-4e2c-a53c-66d0e325281b" />
    
</flow>
    <flow name="GET-RetrieveBatchJobInfo" doc:id="cd7fd6f4-6187-411a-ab66-0fab866cc55a" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="bf635c21-f1ad-4e01-89ed-61310ae03f10" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/batchjob/info" allowedMethods="GET">
            <ee:repeatable-file-store-stream bufferUnit="MB" />
        </http:listener>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="batchjobkey" doc:id="0828bb33-e3c3-4c4c-a998-8650f5b9af44" message="#[attributes.queryParams.batchjobkey]"/>
        <os:retrieve doc:name="Retrieve Number" doc:id="ffe54e6a-0b3e-4d56-937b-e5020c85e491" key="#[attributes.queryParams.batchjobkey]"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="3565b01e-c3d5-404c-aada-7eca12691a4c" message="#[payload]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="d31b6d11-3867-47f4-a610-aba272aba98b" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    
</flow>
    <flow name="GET-BatchJobs" doc:id="dfc66262-d581-439d-936e-a4d9b7d79d38" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="f9924140-091b-425b-9280-17728aadf09f" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/batchjobs" allowedMethods="GET"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="hours" doc:id="b8b1e046-9d12-4a64-8fae-485483de6a73" message="attributes.queryParams.batchjobkey"/>
        <batchmanager:list-all-jobs doc:name="Batch - List All Jobs" doc:id="9478e810-7c10-42a7-beb0-ca40b8111348" arg0="#[attributes.queryParams.hours]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="34e36c58-616a-43c5-b929-a9a136da7544">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    totalRecords: payload01.totalRecords default 0,
    successfulRecords: payload01.successfulRecords default 0,
    creationTime: payload01.creationTime default "",
    processedRecords: payload01.processedRecords default 0,
    batchJobId: payload01.batchJobId default "",
    failedRecords: payload01.failedRecords default 0,
    loadedRecords: payload01.loadedRecords default 0,
    recordCount: payload01.recordCount default 0,
    batchJobName: payload01.batchJobName default "",
    status: payload01.status default "",
    messageFailedOnCompletePhase: payload01.messageFailedOnCompletePhase default null,
    messageFailedOnInputPhase: payload01.messageFailedOnInputPhase default null,
    messageFailedLoadingPhase: payload01.messageFailedLoadingPhase default null,
    stackTrace: payload01.stackTrace default null
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="PATCH-Cancel-BatchJobs" doc:id="0d2313ef-eb0f-48f4-b417-c8708addb0aa" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="17eec8a9-c559-49ac-b7cf-2c4d7c9fff5b" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/batchjobs/cancel" allowedMethods="PATCH" />
        <batchmanager:cancle-batch-job doc:name="Batch Manager - Cancel a Batch Job" doc:id="15e718d2-842e-48c5-ba55-a3ee5d3fae81" arg0="#[payload.batchJobName]" arg1="#[payload.batchJobId]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="1b6f1a94-cdb6-4254-ba2c-bf9e1eb656f4" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="PATCH-Stop-BatchJobs" doc:id="dddc5a75-4c04-493a-a42e-2dd6d4532198" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="c0ce6782-ead7-4562-86af-450ba65356a3" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/batchjobs/stop" allowedMethods="PATCH" />
        <batchmanager:stop-batch-job doc:name="Batch Manager - Stop a Batch Job" doc:id="75276f4a-c33b-44f7-a637-80f6747aae6d" arg0="#[payload.batchJobName]" arg1="#[payload.batchJobId]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="7243d699-7e34-4d03-9022-88bed7f4b534" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="PATCH-Resume-BatchJobs" doc:id="5d211f93-e9c8-4d9c-bdb8-9886e0ad76aa" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="be982ec2-8a72-47db-9909-facb56e96ebd" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/batchjobs/resume" allowedMethods="PATCH" />
        <batchmanager:resume-batch-job doc:name="Batch Manager - Resume a Batch Job" doc:id="0b154314-950d-4824-9498-9d340a51ba6b" arg0="#[payload.batchJobName]" arg1="#[payload.batchJobId]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="567907bd-de4b-4c53-b5a6-fbb2ac8b82c0" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    
</flow>
</mule>
```

I have tried different versions of the 'mule-module-batch-ee' module
('4.5.0-20220622', '4.5.0-20221117', '4.4.0-20220919') and eviroments(CloudHub Runtime version 4.4.0, AnypointStudio Runtime version 4.4.0)
but I still get the same behavior.
I also tried PlektonLabs' BatchMule 4 connector, but I get the same  behavior.

Comment: Why the batch job was stopped originally?

Comment: @aled In this case, the Batch job was stopped manually to test whether the resume function works.
The porpuse of this custom connector is to control the batch processing.